# getting error in django models while using foreign key

Tags: django, django-models

I am using foreign key in django models. But getting error.
models.py:

```
class subscription(models.Model):
  duration_choice = (
    ("Monthly", "Monthly"),
    ("1 Year", "1 Year"),
    ("2 Year", "2 Year"),
  )
  Duration = models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=duration_choice)
  Price=models.IntegerField(default=0)

  def __str__(self):
      return self.Duration


class pro_Members(models.Model):
  subscription_type = models.ForeignKey(subscription,on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
  start_date=models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
  expire_date= models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
  is_active=models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I used subscription models as foreign key in pro_members model. But getting an error.

```
column firmApp_pro_members.subscription_type_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "firmApp_pro_members"."id", "firmApp_pro_members"."su...
```

anyone here can help. I tried my best but can not solve it.

Comment: looks like you did not properly migrated the database...

Answer (score 0):

when you add a new field into your Model Django tries to add this field to exist objects you can solve this like this:

```
class pro_Members(models.Model):
    subscription_type = models.ForeignKey(subscription,on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="", blank=True, null=True)
```

and then

```
> python manage.py makemigrations
> python manage.py migrate
```

and change back to:

```
class pro_Members(models.Model):
    subscription_type = models.ForeignKey(subscription,on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
```

Comment: still same error

Comment: that means your error is in somewhere else. It should show in which line the error is. Check this and focus on this line

Comment: Thanks, sir, I solved my error. The error was in the database that is not going to update. I migrated many times but not. Then I create a new database after that its works.